# httpServletResponse behavior in chrome and firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, download

I have a controller method in charge of an excel download:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getUserReport(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String user,
                          @RequestParam(value = "startdate", required = false) String startDate,
                          @RequestParam(value = "enddate", required = false) String endDate,
                          HttpServletResponse response) {

    List<Survey> userSurveys = surveyService.findUserSurveys(user, startDate, endDate);


    String userFileName = nameService.getUserFileName(user, startDate, endDate);
    Workbook userExcelReport = excelReportGenerator.createUserExcelReport(userSurveys);

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + userFileName + ".xlsx");


    try {
        userExcelReport.write(response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("The excel workbook could not write to the outputStream ", e);
    }

}
```

as you can see this controller mapping is tanking a excel workbook (done in apache poi) and setting the header and content type, in google chrome this works perfectly but in firefox the file is downloaded as a "file" with no extension (but the data is correct as if i open the file with excel all is there) and the name is built wrong, as in chrome this works completely fine i assume there is something wrong the way the response works in firefox, anyone has idea what could i be doing wrong?

example of downloaded files trough firefox [image: image with files not working]
example of downloads using chrome [image]

Comment: According [RFC 6266](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#page-4) the `filename` `value` is either a `token` or a  `quoted-string`. So try `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + userFileName + ".xlsx\"");`

Comment: @AxelRichter this did the trick, care to post as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#page-4) the filename `value` is either a `token` or a `quoted-string`.

A `token` must not contain `separators`. But white space is a `separator`. So you must using a `quoted-string`.

So try

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + userFileName + ".xlsx\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this way to sent content type in response. It works for me.

```
resp.setContentType( "application/octet-stream" );
```